# How to propagate the action from SKScene component to UIViewController

Tags: pushviewcontroller, skscene

in XCode 12, using Swift 5, create a new Project using the Game SpriteKit technology. That generates amongst other things:

- GameViewController.swift
- GameScene.swift

In GameScene.swift I added

1. after the class definition

   ```
   let tapRec2 = UITapGestureRecognizer()
   ```
2. in override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

   ```
   tapRec2.addTarget(self, action:#selector(GameScene.tappedView2(_:) ))
   tapRec2.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
   tapRec2.numberOfTapsRequired = 2  //2 taps i
   self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(tapRec2)
   ```
3. the implementation of tappedView2 function to detect a double tap.

   ```
   @objc func tappedView2(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
     let controller = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
     let new_controller = ViewController()
     print("double click detected")
     controller?.navigationController?.pushViewController(new_controller, 
     animated: true)
   }
   ```

- I then created a ViewController class using the template https://gist.github.com/phynet/075d538c93c0bfe62596bc4d47a482e1

I compiled it and run it, the app starts appropriately and if I do a double click it detects it, however no ViewController is displayed. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

found the solution by simplifying tappedView2 to the following code:

```
  @objc func tappedView2(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let new_controller = ViewController()
    self.view?.window?.rootViewController = new_controller
  }
```

and simplified the UIViewController to:

```
  import UIKit
  import Foundation
  class ViewController: UIViewController  {

      override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
      }
  }
```

Comment: The approach followed to start the new controller is inappropriate since it replaces the rootViewController instead of pushViewController.